# How would one simplify this multiple select query for faster execution?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b88d1a/1/0   --- Note I could not load enough inserts into SQLFiddle due to some 8000 character limit, and without a minimum amount of data the query can't run. So the SQL inserts is in this pastebin file: https://pastebin.com/MfhJ0Svc   -- I could not paste the 320 insert lines in Fiddle or SO sorry.

I have one table, and then a view called Reviewed that contains a single column with only unique usernames. The table is called RebasedQuestions and contains about 40000 records for now.

The table was used to calculate a set of reviews done by people on people.

The query needs to produce a final table that gives the values for supervisor, own, peer and subordinate as a percentage, and then as a value out of 6 (the review question options ranged from 1 to 6). And the weights per review type are:

```
Supervisor: 30%
Own: 0%
Peer: 40%
Subordinate: 30%
```

[image]

Here is the DDL for the view:

```
CREATE VIEW Reviewed AS
  SELECT DISTINCT `t1`.`Reviewed` AS `Reviewed`
  FROM `edsdb`.`RebasedQuestions` `t1`
  ORDER BY `t1`.`Reviewed`;
```

And the DDL for the main table:

```
create table RebasedQuestions
(
    Reviewed varchar(50) null,
    ReviewType varchar(20) null,
    BU int null,
    RebasedValue double null
)
;
```

Here is my query, but I think it is far from optimized, so please enlighten me as to how to speed this up, especially as the main table is growing with 20 lines every time a new review is submitted:

```
select DISTINCT t1.Reviewed, t2.BU,
  (SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Supervisor') AS Supervisor,
  (((SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Supervisor')/100) * 6) as Sup6,
  (SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Own') AS Own,
  (((SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Own')/100) * 6) as Own6,
  (SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Peer') AS Peer,
  (((SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Peer')/100) * 6) as Peer6,
  (SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Subordinate') AS Subordinate,
  (((SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Subordinate')/100) * 6) as Sub6,
  (ifnull((((SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Supervisor')/100) * 6),6) * 0.3 +
  ifnull((((SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Peer')/100) * 6),6) * 0.4 +
  ifnull((((SELECT ((sum(t2.RebasedValue)/(count(t2.RebasedValue)/20))) from RebasedQuestions t2 WHERE t2.Reviewed = t1.Reviewed and t2.ReviewType = 'Subordinate')/100) * 6),6) * 0.3) as Totaled
from Reviewed t1  JOIN RebasedQuestions t2 on t1.Reviewed = t2.Reviewed
```

I cant even paste the inserts here in the body.

They can be found on this pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/MfhJ0Svc

Comment: Can you also provide some sample and desired data

Comment: Please provide sample input and the output you expect.  I'd be shocked if there weren't a much more efficient query than what you wrote, even without any tuning.

Comment: as @MKhalidJunaid said and please it would be really good if use this tool 
 sqlfiddle.com

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I provided the SQL fiddle and enough sql inserts on pastebin (sqlfiddle and SO would not allow me to paste 320 rows.

Comment: is RebasedQuestions.Reviewed a foreign key, and is the foreign key constraint on this column enforced in your schema?

Comment: @Taemyr Hi Taemyr, no it is not a foreign key. The view was created only to have distinct usernames to join against.

Comment: What is this BU value.  Are there reviewed with more than one BU value? - Because if there is your query will return one row pr BU value, but sum for all rows with that reviewed.

Comment: @Taemyr The BU stays constant per Reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that you should be able to adapt to your need.

```
SELECT 
innerQuery.Reviewed,
innerQuery.BU,
(CASE WHEN (innerQuery.supcount=0) then null else 
innerQuery.suptot/innerQuery.supcount end) as sup,
(CASE WHEN (innerQuery.supcount=0) then null else 
(6*innerQuery.suptot)/(100*innerQuery.supcount) end) as sup6
 ...
(CASE WHEN (innerQuery.supcount=0) then 1.8 else sup6*0.3 end)+ ... as totaled
from  
(SELECT 
Reviewed, 
BU,
(SUM(ReviewType='Supervisor') then RebasedValue else 0 end) as 
suptot
(COUNT(ReviewType='Supervisor') then RebasedValue else 0 end) as 
supcount,
...
FROM RebasedQuestions GROUP BY Reviewed, BU) innerQuery
```

Comment: On mobile atm, thanks for the answer. Will test and reply back asap ;)